# Update content of list in a map

Tags: java

I have a map, what I want to do is update the content for a specified key of a map.
Below is my sample code,  I will get and save to a tempList first,
then update the tempList and then save back to the valueMap;

```
Map<String, List<Number>> valueMap = new HashMap<String, List<Number>>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry2 : innerMap.entrySet()) {
    for(String str : titleList){
        if(str.equals(entry2.getKey())){
            List<Number> tempList = valueMap.get(str);
            tempList.add((Number) entry2.getValue());
            valueMap.put(str, tempList);
         }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know is there an easy/pretty way to do that same operation.

Update the entry2 part's code ( I thought it will not cause confusion at the first time, my fault. )

Comment: what is entry2 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is `entry2` but it can be rewrite like this:

```java
titleList.stream()
        .filter(entry2.getKey()::equals)
        .forEach(str -> valueMap
                .computeIfAbsent(str, (x) -> new ArrayList<Number>())
                .add((Number) entry2.getValue()));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, I believe this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save the `List` to the `Map` again after fetching and adding an item, as the `List` you have updated is still saved in the `Map`:

```java
Map<String, List<Number>> valueMap = new HashMap<String, List<Number>>();

for (String str : titleList){
    if(str.equals(entry2.getKey())) {
        List<Number> tempList = valueMap.get(str);
        tempList.add((Number) entry2.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a Map just isn't the correct collection type for this job. Multimaps are designed to have multiple values for the same key. Im not sure if the JDK collection framework contains any implementations for Multimaps, so you probably have to rely on a third party library. Guava has Multimap's and Apache Commons has a MultiValuedMap.